# Push notification using Strapi

Tags: strapi

I want to build a friend relationship function. My question:
If user A sends a relationship request to user B, how can I let Strapi send (push) a notification to user B?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I found an example here: medium.com/strapi/strapi-socket-io-a9c856e915a6 in this example a message is sent to every user. Unfortunately I have no experience with Socket.io and do not know how to assign a Connection ID to a user who has already logged in. Has someone a tip for me?

Comment: Hello! Can you please precise how your "send a relationship request" using Strapi. This will let me know how to do that matching your way.

Comment: @JimLAURIE Hello Jim, I have a contentType called "Relationship" with "userA_Id, userB_Id, userB_email_hash, etc.". UserA is requester and enters email of UserB. UserB is responder. If userB can find the value of "userB_email_hash", its ID is entered in "userB_Id". Then UserA should receive a notification that the "relationship" has been successfully created. Thanks in advance!